# Make a table tighter and a caption centered / not too close from table

Tags: tables, spacing, horizontal-alignment, captions, center

I would like to get a tighter table since I have too much space between rows and columns.

Here below the current Latex code:

```
   \begin{table*}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{*{7}{c}}
      \hline
      \\
      \text{ Modified Gravity - FoM - XC2/XC} & \text { semi-pessimistic } & \text { optimistic } \\
      \\
      \hline
      \\
      \text{ Flat} & 534/485   & 1227/725  \\
      \text { Gain } & 59.9 \% & +69.2 \% \\
      \\
      \hline \\
      \text { Non-Flat} & 177/141  & 583/464  \\
      \text { Gain } &  +25.5 \% & +25.6 \%\\
      \\
      \hline        
      
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table comparing XC2 and XC (Modified Gravity) for all cases considered.}
    \label{table_XC2_MG}
    \end{table*}
```

Moreover, the caption is not centered and too closed to the last line and I wonder how to fix this.

The rendering is for the moment :

[image: current result]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Oh, and what's the purpose of encasing the material in column 1 in `\text` wrappers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Your table code is quite strange:

  - why you use `table*` environment? Does your document has two column and you like that table span both columns?
  - Why you enclose all text in table in `\text` command? Remove them!
    -Why you put `\\` after `\hline`s?
- to make table narrower you should enable to break column headers into two lines. For example by use of `\makecell` packageČ
- However, MWE )Minimal Working Example) below is just guessing. We don't know, which document class you use, ar your document has two columns, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[h!]
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{*{3}{c}}
      \hline
\makecell{Modified Gravity\\ FoM - XC2/XC} 
            & \makecell{semi-\\pessimistic}
                                & optimistic    \\
    \hline
Flat        & 534/485           & 1227/725      \\
Gain        & 59.9 \%           & +69.2 \%      \\
    \hline
Non-Flat    & 177/141           & 583/464       \\
Gain        &  +25.5 \%         & +25.6 \%      \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Table comparing XC2 and XC (Modified Gravity) for all cases considered.}
\label{table_XC2_MG}
    \end{table*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can write table on more nicer way. For example with use of `booktabs` and `tabularray` packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {*{3}{Q[c,m]}}}
      \toprule
{Modified Gravity\\ FoM - XC2/XC} 
            & {semi-\\pessimistic}
                                & optimistic    \\
    \midrule
Flat        & 534/485           & 1227/725      \\
Gain        & 59.9 \%           & +69.2 \%      \\
    \midrule
Non-Flat    & 177/141           & 583/464       \\
Gain        &  +25.5 \%         & +25.6 \%      \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
\caption{Table comparing XC2 and XC (Modified Gravity) for all cases considered.}
\label{table_XC2_MG}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For further suggestion you should provide MWE, from which we can see which document class you use and what is layout of your document.

Comment: thanks a lot, it works well !